# How to make common method which would be call from any component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have components some of which use the same function (in client-side JavaScript controller).
At this moment i resolved this problem putting this function in each component. But it isn't comfortable :(
I tried to use tag aura:method with access="global" in main component and invoke it from child ones but it isn't work.

How to resolve this problem without using events?

Comment: If its a common method make it in separate class as static method and pass necessary values as parameters.

Comment: @Reshma This is referring to JavaScript, not Apex Code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to "share" at the moment is to use the extends keyword. If you create a component, and then use the extends attribute on a child component, that component's helper are available to the child. See [What is Inherited?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_whats_inherited.htm) for additional things that are inherited when you extend a component.

Comment: From guide: "We don't recommend using inheritance of client-side controllers as this feature may be deprecated in the future to preserve better component encapsulation. We recommend that you put common code in a helper instead."

Comment: @TPEHEP They're referring to the *controller*, not the *helper.* That quote also mentions that you should put shared methods in the helper.

Comment: @sfdxfox It's perfect! I created new extensible component with neccessary methods in helper and markup {!v.body}. Than extended components which use that methods and magic )). Helper methods in extensible component getting in "__proto__" property of extended component helper. Thank you very much for help!